# Confusing MySQL error/warning/info message

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu

I am having trouble administering my MySQL.  I tried to stop it like this:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

and I got this message:

```
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mysql stop

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the stop(8) utility, e.g. stop mysql
```

So I tried doing this:

```
$ sudo  mysql stop
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
$ sudo  mysql start
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

My OS is Ubuntu.  Any ideas why I seem to be running into this dead end? :)

Comment: Did you try `service mysql stop` ?

Comment: @ypercube $ service mysql stop
stop: Unknown instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need superuser rights to run `service`:

```
$ sudo service mysql stop
```

or (as root):

```
# service mysql stop
```

Using the `service` and `chkconfig` utilities is now the defacto standard for service initscript handling on most Linux distributions.

EDIT:

If none of the above works, you can try `mysqladmin` directly:

```
$ sudo mysqladmin shutdown
```

Comment: @thkala the "sudo service mysql stop" command gave this error message: "stop: Unknown instance:"

Comment: @Genadinik: Have you tried `sudo mysqladmin shutdown` directly?

Answer (score 0):

Read that message again.

> ...use the `service(8)` utility, e.g. `service mysql stop`
>
> ...you may also use the `stop(8)` utility, e.g. `stop mysql`

You're mixing the two together, which ends up running the `mysql` command-line client and trying to connect to the `stop` and `start` *databases* on the local server (which apparently isn't running).

Pick one or the other.  Note that either one will need `sudo` in front of it if you're not logged in as root.

And, in case it wasn't obvious, `mysql-server` needs to be installed correctly for any of this to work.  It's starting to sound like something's a bit borked about your install.

Comment: @chao in both cases it tells me that it is an unknown utility.  Where should I run it from?  The directory I am doing this in is /var/run

Comment: It doesn't matter where you run it from; it works everywhere, as long as you're root (and of course, have the MySQL server installed).